# <td> tags are stripped from text when injected in MooTools Elements

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, mootools

I'm trying to build some JavaScript in MooTools that fetches table row markup from the server, then adds it to a table. I have an object named `htmlAjax` that's set as a MooTools `Ajax` object. The object gets the HTML from the server correctly (tested this in the Firebug console), but when I attempt to add this markup to a new element, the `<td>` elements get stripped out. Here is my function that captures the data from the HTTP request and attempts to add a row:

```
htmlAjax.addEvent('onComplete', function (data) {
    var slot = new Element('tr');
    slot.setHTML(data);
    slot.injectInside($('volunteer_slots'));
});
```

The response I get back from the server in `data` looks like this:

```
<td><div class="title" rel="60">
    <a class="modal" href="index.php?view=volunteerslot&amp;tmpl=component&amp;id=60" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 650, y: 550}}" >test</a>
</div>
</td>
<td class="button_column">
    <img src="images/publish_x.png" />
</td>
<td>0 minutes</td>
<td><select name="volunteers[60]" id="volunteers60" class="inputbox"><option value="0"  selected="selected">(select...)</option><option value="63" >Joe LeBlanc</option><option value="64" >Test User</option><option value="65" >Test User</option><option value="66" >Test User</option><option value="67" >Test User</option></select></td>
<td><select name="total_time_spent[60][hours]" id="total_time_spent60hours" ><option value="0"  selected="selected">0</option><option value="1" >1</option><option value="2" >2</option><option value="3" >3</option><option value="4" >4</option><option value="5" >5</option><option value="6" >6</option><option value="7" >7</option><option value="8" >8</option><option value="9" >9</option><option value="10" >10</option><option value="11" >11</option><option value="12" >12</option><option value="13" >13</option><option value="14" >14</option><option value="15" >15</option><option value="16" >16</option><option value="17" >17</option><option value="18" >18</option><option value="19" >19</option><option value="20" >20</option><option value="21" >21</option><option value="22" >22</option><option value="23" >23</option><option value="24" >24</option></select>&nbsp;hours&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="total_time_spent[60][minutes]" id="total_time_spent60minutes" ><option value="0"  selected="selected">0</option><option value="15" >15</option><option value="30" >30</option><option value="45" >45</option></select>&nbsp;minutes</td>
<td class="button_column">
    <img src="images/tick.png" />
</td>
```

Once I call `setHTML` on the `slot` variable (passing in `data`), the `<tbody>` element `volunteer_slots` has a new row, but that new row contains everything except for the `<td>` elements. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite interesting.  While I can't explain it, I do have a solution for you.  Reverse the order of your `setHTML()` and `injectInside()` lines, and the `<td>`s are inserted properly:

```
slot.injectInside($('volunteer_slots'));
slot.setHTML(data);
```

You are apparently using MooTools 1.11, however, this behaviour appears to occur in 1.2 as well.  Very odd!  It must have something to do with the fact that before the `slots` var is injected, it is not part of the DOM.  The effects of setting the innerHTML of a non-DOM element might be unexpected?  I wish I could explain it.  I'll have to dig deeper when I have time.

Comment: good catch this. mootools does sometimes do odd things with elements it injects, I have had it mess up style from block to inline on elements injected into a div with overflow...

Answer (score 0):

What version of MooTools are you using? I'm not sure if it has anything to do with that, but in the latest version, there is no (as far as I'm aware) `setHTML` method, it's now `set('html', data)`. I also believe that `injectInside` has become `slot.inject($('volunteer_slots'))`. Hope this helps.